# How can I use UDP Multicast in Silverlight4?

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0

How can I use UDP Multicast? Who can help me?
I have some sample, but it does not work.
Who can explain me how to work with this technology?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure this out myself, but I ran across [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707325) that was helpful. Maybe it will help you.